# Is it possible to write sql conn.cursor() and commit() into python function?

Tags: python, sqlite

As title, I am trying writing a python function:

```
def sql(sql):
    cursor=conn.cursor() 
    cursor.execute(sql)
    conn.commit()
```

So when I want to commit something with python sqlite3, just use `sql(""" SELECT * FROM table WHERE ....""")`
But it seems not working..

Comment: You don't need to commit a `SELECT` query, only queries that make changes to the DB.

Comment: How do you expect to use that function with a `SELECT` query? You don't return the cursor, so there's no way for the caller to fetch the results.

Comment: "seems not working". What are you expecting, and what's happening instead?

Comment: I don't use SQLlite, only psycopg2, but i'm pretty sure he needs to ```return cursor.fetchall()``` at the end of the function if it's a select statement.

Comment: I am using this function with CREATE TABLE and CREATE INDEX, so need commit()

Comment: I also want to use this for SELECT data, as you mention, there's no need for commit()